# Why does the exponential-function domain need greater than zero and unequal to one?

Tags: exponential-function

For example, f(x) = 0ˣ. Is it a exponent? Is it a function? I think f(x) = 0ˣ is an exponential function, but it's base is zero. Do you think? Can you help me?

Comment: Look up the definition of an exponential function!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I knowed after I saw this document(http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6500/ClassSit/Major/Exponential%20Bases.pdf). Thanks a lot.